# How to pass different lines of a matrix to threadPool. [ JAVA ]

Tags: java, concurrency

Im trying to get a threadPool of n threads to compute the values for each line of a matrix and return a new one. The code i got so far does its job at creating the threads and making a basis for the tasks that need to be completed but im not sure how to go about passing a different line of the same matrix for each thread.

For example,if its a 3x3 matrix,we would have 3 threads.
1'st thread -> gets first horizontal line of matrix,computes and changes the values,adds it to new matrix

2'nd thread -> gets second horizontal line of matrix...

3'rd thread -> ...

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                  //take row of matrix
                  //compute new row
                  //add to result matrix                    }
                    });
                }

    threadPool.shutdown();
    threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Seems like homework, but where are your matrices? What is the data structure? An nxn array? A custom class? Something else?

Comment: Its a huge project of which this is less that 1/10'th of. Just need tips for concurrency,looking at some code right now but its difficult to read. I cant post the entire code because it is for uni and i dont want to plagiarise. The matrix is an array of type int[n][m]. I have the code which computes the values correctly,i just dont know how to pass it line by line to a threadpool and combine the results into a similar nxm matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that in 2D array `int[][] array = new int[N][M]` invoking `array[n]` will return n-th row, you can then pass that row to each thread:

```
int[][] array = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12,13,14,15} };

ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(array.length);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    final int finalI = i;
    threadPool.submit(() -> {
        int[] row = array[finalI];
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + Arrays.toString(row));
        for(int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            row[j] *= 2;
        }
    });
}

threadPool.shutdown();
while(!threadPool.isTerminated()) {
    Thread.sleep(20);
}

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int[] row = array[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(row[j] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

will print:

```
pool-1-thread-4: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
pool-1-thread-1: [1, 2, 3]
pool-1-thread-2: [4, 5, 6]
pool-1-thread-3: [7, 8, 9]
2, 4, 6, 
8, 10, 12, 
14, 16, 18, 
20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30,
```

Comment: Unfortunately im getting a local variable issue with the lambda expression. I declared the final int finalI = i but i still cant use it within the expression. Not sure why.

Comment: What error are you getting? Which Java version are you running this on?